# How to check logs for running container on Heroku?

Tags: java, docker, heroku, containers

I deployed a sample `Java` app like container on `Heroku`. I made `heroku container:push <name>` and `heroku container:release <name>` afterwards. Commands worked but I don't understand if the app itself is running since it should fire few times per day.

I tried to see general logs, got nothing. Where can I find container-related logs in Heroku?

UPDATE:

My logs are the following:

> 2019-12-18T21:21:20.002711+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user
>
> 2019-12-18T21:21:20.002711+00:00 app[api]: Deployed worker
> (c77c435c1355) by user

After this, no logs appeared.

Comment: have you run `heroku logs`?

Comment: @codefinger I added logs into my post. Should I add anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a logging framework (log4j, java Logging) you still need to initialise it to log to the stdout (Console), you should then be able to see your logs in the Heroku "View Logs" (or indeed with CLI heroku logs).

Are you using log4j? Add log4j.properties in the classpath of your apps.
You can also try the System.out.println to log into the stdout.

Hope it helps.

Beppe

Comment: The problem is slightly different my application is logging but it is logging inside the container on Heroku. My question was rather how to expose these logs any further like Kibana, Sentry, or any other logging software.

Answer (score 0):

As @Beppe C's answer mentions, I can use log4j or similar logging solutions.

There are a couple of possibilities for logging.

1. Use plugins in Heroku such as Papertrail that will scrape logs from Docker and post them into themselves. You can see, filter, search, and archive logs there.
2. Use external systems such as Sentry, AWS Cloudwatch, you name it. You will need to set up appenders and config to where to send logs. They will be sent from application. You will see only application-specific logs, not Heroku specific as in the 1st solution.

You have two main options, and sometimes it's just a good idea to use them both.